# Provide an async get() function for a theading based queue

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I have a simple queue that uses a `threading.Condition` to deal with consumers that wait at an empty queue.

I want this queue also to be consumed by `async` code.

That's why I added a `get_async` method.

The problem is now in the `consumer` below. It uses `asyncio.wait_for` since I wanted to see whether my queue is safe to be cancelled. Now the observation is, that after I induce the cancellation, my consumer always runs into a timeout.

I guess that this is caused by the `CancellationError` that prevents the `self.condition` from being released properly.

Can someone give me a hint what's going wrong here?

```py
import threading
import time
import asyncio

SENTINEL = object()


class Queue:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.items = []
        self.condition = threading.Condition()

    def put(self, item):
        with self.condition:
            self.items.append(item)
            self.condition.notify()

    def get(self):
        with self.condition:
            while not self.items:
                self.condition.wait()
            return self.items.pop(0)

    async def get_async(self):
        try:
            loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
            return await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: self.get())
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("I've been cancelled and I think the self.condition is now broken")


async def consumer(n: int, queue: Queue):
    while True:
        try:
            # if I leave out the "wait_for" or make it longer than my sleep(2) below,
            # it works
            item = await asyncio.wait_for(queue.get_async(), 5)
            if item is SENTINEL:
                print(f"consumer {n=} got SENTINEL")
                queue.put(item)
                break
            else:
                print(f"consumer {n=} got {item=}")
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("got timeout")


def producer(queue: Queue):
    queue.put("foo")
    queue.put("bar")
    time.sleep(2)
    queue.put("baz")
    queue.put(SENTINEL)


q = Queue()
t = threading.Thread(target=producer, args=(q,))
t.start()

asyncio.run(consumer(0, q))

t.join()
```

With a "long enough" timeout (or without `wait_for` at all) the output is

```
consumer n=0 got item='foo'
consumer n=0 got item='bar'
consumer n=0 got item='baz'
consumer n=0 got SENTINEL
```

When I induce the cancellation, it's

```
consumer n=0 got item='foo'
consumer n=0 got item='bar'
got timeout
got timeout
got timeout
got timeout
got timeout
(and so on)
```

It should be like:

```
consumer n=0 got item='foo'
consumer n=0 got item='bar'
got timeout
got timeout
got timeout
got timeout
consumer n=0 got item='baz'
consumer n=0 got SENTINEL
```

Answer (score 2):

Cancelling an "async thread" only cancels *waiting* for the thread. It does not cancel what the thread is doing.

As the threads run `self.get()`, they *will* consume an item as soon as it is available. Cancelling the "async thread" part merely means that the async code proceeds and *discards the item* provided by `self.get()`.
As a result, cancelling one thread (1 < timeout < 2) discards the `'baz'` item and cancelling two threads (timeout < 1) also discards the `SENTINEL` – trapping the consumer in an infinite loop.

---

Instead of synchronising *and consuming an item* between async/thread code, only synchronise async/thread code and handle item consumption explicitly. This allows to safely ignore the first part but cancel the latter.

A simple albeit inefficient approach is to a) `notify_all` when an item becomes available and b) await `condition.wait()` via threads.

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.items = []
        self.condition = threading.Condition()

    def put(self, item):
        with self.condition:
            self.items.append(item)
            # wake up *everyone* who is waiting – they check for items anyway
            self.condition.notify_all()

    async def get_async(self):
        def wait():
            with self.condition:
                self.condition.wait()
        try:
            loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
            while True:
                while not self.items:
                    await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: wait())
                # another thread may get the item inbetween
                # be defensive and retry on failure
                try:
                    return self.items.pop(0)
                except IndexError:
                    continue
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            print("I've been cancelled while waiting for an item")

    ...
```

Comment: *inefficient* because many consumers may be notified although only one item is available, that's the background, correct? Thank you very much for the updated example!

Comment: @user4344 Indeed, waking up every consumer is the inefficiency. If you have many consumers at once but only few/individual items then the consumers mostly waste time checking for items. That shouldn't be much of a problem unless the application does very little else, though.